# Django session cookie marked as "third party" and blocked by Firefox

Tags: django, nginx, firefox, cookies

When I log in to my Django-based server using Firefox, the cookie passed to the browser gets marked as "Third Party" and thus gets blocked by default, with no option offered to create an exception, even though the cookie shows as being from "https://servername" which is identical to the URL. I found that if I access the server as "https://servername.domain.lol" instead of directly as "https://servername", the cookie gets marked correctly as first-party. I really don't want to force all users to use the FQDN instead of just the server name. Is there some way in Django or in my Nginx reverse proxy to set some header or something such that the browser will recognize that the cookie belongs to this site?

Comment: what is servername if it's not a FQDN? A local network server? It doesn't have the `.local`?

Comment: And when you look at the response headers from your Django server in your browser dev tools, what do you see in the `Set-Cookie` header for "domain"?

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't see that key in the ``set-cookie`` header

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, it's a server on the local work network. All users will be on the local work network or VPN'd in, so I'd prefer to allow direct access to the server using its short hostname since we share URL's a lot and having the FQDN adds clutter which shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @dirkgroten setting either "hostname" or "hostname.domain.lol" as the domain in the set-cookie header makes the cookie not get used at all, breaking sessions and thus login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you get your DNS server to respond without the domain?

Nevertheless, besides from configuring the DNS correctly I would suggest to simply let nginx respond with the FQDN. Either by a redirect or by returning a 301.

```
server {
   listen 443;
   server_name servername servername.domain.lol;
   return 301 https://servername.domain.lol$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This answer does get around the issue by doing what I already said made things work. However, it's still puzzling to me why the cookie and URL can share the same name, and yet still Firefox considers it a third-party cookie. Since the server is only ever used from within our work network, using the short hostname is more convenient, and I'd much rather figure out how to make that work rather than throw in the towel and just forward everyone to the longer URL just because Firefox doesn't behave intuitively otherwise.

Comment: @scnerd settings this wouldn't mean your users *must* use the full uri, they can still use the short one. Regarding FF, this seems to me like normal behaviour, as FF first tries to make the request an RFC conform uri and setting the cookie accordingly. If you really want to check the reason I would suggest having a look in the FF source - maybe a dev chat may also shed some light on it.